# Select Current users schema when calling a function T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to call a user defined function from a stored procedure, is it possible to invoke this dynamically based on the currently logged in user?

for example, i am trying to execute the user defined function like this.

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME().ITEM_CNT(8,1315)
```

where SCHEMA_NAME() is the currently logged on users schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by only using Dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100);

SET @SQL = N'
    SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME()) + '.ITEM_CNT(8, 1315);';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

If you need to use value, returned by function, later, you could insert it into temporary table and then just query it.

Something like that:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(200);

CREATE TABLE #ITEM_CNT
(
    RESULT INT
);

SET @SQL = N'
    INSERT INTO #ITEM_CNT (RESULT)
    SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME()) + '.ITEM_CNT(8, 1315);';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;

SELECT RESULT
FROM #ITEM_CNT;
```